# LISP conditional loops

Tags: while-loop, lisp, common-lisp

Fairly new to LISP,

I'm trying to create a loop that repeatedly generate new random codes for every duplicate element in a list, I have a successful elim-duplicates helper function that removes duplicate lists in my all-guesses variable, I want my loop to continue making new guesses until ALL my lists in all-guesses are unique, population-amount is an integer value

```
 (loop 
        while (< (length (elim-duplicates all-guess)) population-amount)
        do((elim-duplicates all-guess)))
```

Comment: instead of removing, why add duplicates in the first place.

Comment: I tried using an if statement to ignore duplicates in my random-guess-generator. I kept running into errors when trying to add if statements in my loop

Comment: If you want some random integers that can't repeat, consider whether a viable alternative might not be to generate a list of consecutive integers which are then shuffled.

Comment: nvm, figured it out